# Jsp list output Object@488584?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a list of tweets inside a user and when I iterate through them all I get is the object but not the actual text

```
<c:forEach items = "${tweets}" var="user" ></c:forEach>

  <h1><c:out value="${user.tweets}" /></h1>
  </div>
```

how do I get the value of the tweets, they all save as text in the databse but don't display properly on the page.

Comment: Is List of tweets a list<string> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I see wrong. First if your code is really as posted and not a typo, than you should note that you don't print anything inside a loop as you just iterate and never do anything with the `user` variable

The following

```
<c:forEach items = "${tweets}" var="user" ></c:forEach>
```

should be something like

```
<c:forEach items = "${tweets}" var="user" >
   <c:out value="${user.tweets}"
</c:forEach>
```

Also, I've seen in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854558/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-tweets-available-a) of yours the structure of your `User` class. The `tweets` property is a list, so you should iterate over it just like you iterate the `tweets` model attribute, so something like

```
<c:forEach items = "${user.tweets}" var="singleTweet" >
   <c:out value="${singleTweet.tweet}"
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: holy sssh, thank you so much! hey quick q, how would i add the user name pertaining to the tweet? I'm working on that and how to add a button to follow someone. THank for answering this, so relieved